# How to specify a type based on the object returned by a function

Tags: flowtype

If I create an object using a constructor function

```
function Person(name: string) {this.name = name;}
```

how would I specify the type returned by the constructor function?

```
function hello(person: ???): string {
   return 'hello ' + person.name;
}

const person = new Person('John');
hello(person);
```

Comment: `{ name: string }`? See [the docs](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/).

Comment: The `new` keyword will always return the new Object instance. It won't return the string like you are expecting.

Comment: @jonrsharpe This would imply that all object with the same properties are the same. I would imagine, that two objects with different constructor function must also be different for flow.

Comment: No, it implies that all objects with the same properties *have the same properties*. The code consuming it just cares whether or not it has a `.name` it can add to `'hello '`.

Comment: @RossAllen Why do you think that I expect new Person to return a string?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Still confused. Does this mean that I really have to specify all properties of the object? Is there no shortcut like when using a class where the class name can be used? What when using prototypal inheritance?

Comment: Good question. As a workaround you can convert `Person` to class, and then easily use `Person` as a type.

Comment: might be helpful: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2840

Comment: @Alex I understand that the ES6 class syntax is an alternative to the classic constructor function. There is a lot of existing code that does not use class and still should be type checked and there is very little documentation on how to deal with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to describe your constructor function in an interface as you would do with a normal class implementation and use it within your `hello` function:

```js
/* @flow */

interface IPerson {
  name: string;
}

function Person(name: string) {
  this.name = name;
}

function hello(person: IPerson): string {
  return 'hello ' + person.name;
}

const person = new Person('John');
hello(person);
```

However I would recommend against using constructor functions instead of regular classes because the point of interfaces in Flow are to be implemented by classes in order to type-guard them:

```js
class Person implements IPerson {}
```